# "Insert 'ClassBody' to complete ClassDeclaration" when a switch is contained in class

Tags: java, eclipse

When I add a `switch` to a certain class (containing nothing else) I get the following error (I'm using Eclipse):

```
Syntax error, insert "ClassBody" to complete ClassDeclaration
```

I know that the problem is with this class specifically (and with the switch) because when I delete the switch the error disappears.

My code:

```
class IsJoin {

    switch (args[0]) {

    default:
        return true;
    }

}
```

What could be causing this error? All other similar questions I've found involve missing brackets, but that's not the case here.

Comment: The `switch` statement must occur within a method.

Comment: You can't just put code in a class body like that. Code must be in a method or constructor or initializer block.

Comment: @DominikSandjaja Thanks for your help. I understand it now.

Comment: @greg-449 Okay, thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code must be in a method or constructor or initializer block. For example, this would work:

```
public class IsJoin {
    public boolean isJoin(String[] args) {

        switch (args[0]) {

        default:
            return false;
        }   
    }
}
```